# Как передать изображение с одного Активити на другое?

Tags: android

У меня есть 2 Активити. В обеих Активити есть ава пользователя куда ставится изображение. Так вот. Я хочу передать установленную Аву пользователем, с одной Активити на другую. Как это сделать? Скажите пожалуйста. Это можно сделать с помощью Intent?

Comment: Кешируй изображение и передавай url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы не рекомендовал вам передавать изображения через bundle. Bundle создан для передачи простых данных. Да никто не запрещает вам положить и более сложный объект в bundle, но надо помнить, что размер bundl-a ограничен (по-моему 1 МБ, но могу и ошибаться). А значит если ваше изображение будет больше 1 МБ ваше приложение упадет.

Для таких вещей рекомендуется кешировать их. Это может быть база данных, какая-то сущность которая живет отдельно от ваших View (Activity, Fragment) в течении всего приложения, можно сохранять на диск. А при переходе не новую активити передавать ссылку или id на изображение в bundl-е и открывать ее снова.

Comment: Спасибо вам!!!! Всем!! За ответы. Реально помогли.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов. Вариант 1:

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

и в принимающей активности:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Либо второй вариант - передавать массив байтов:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
Bitmap b; // ваша картинка
ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
i.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
startActivity(i);
```

и дальше извлекаем в другой активности:

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {
    ImageView previewThumbnail = new ImageView(this);
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
        getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"),0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);        
    previewThumbnail.setImageBitmap(b);
}
```

Comment: Разве первый и последний варианты не одинаковые?

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов, да одинаковые, спасибо что указали на это :) исправил ответ :)

Comment: @Andrew а как ограничение Bundle в 1 MB?

Comment: @danilshik, это один из вариантов, если изображения будут большими то проще в кэш сохранять